# Why solvability implies sequence of normal extensions?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Purely from a field theory perspective, can anyone explain through plain intuition why solvability of a polynomial implies the existence of a chain of **normal extensions** of a field than just extensions?

Comment: First adjoin all the roots of unity you need, cyclotomic extensions are always normal.  If you have all the $n$-th roots of unity, then adjoining $\sqrt[n]{a}$ gives a normal extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *any* polynomial corresponds to a chain of extensions, but if those extensions are not "radical" extensions, then you can't express the roots of the polynomial in terms of radicals. So, solvability implies the existence of a chain of radical extensions. But every chain of radical extensions can be expanded to a chain of normal extensions by doing as Wojowu writes in a comment: first, toss in all the roots of unity you need, then toss in all the radicals you need.

Comment: A quick observation here - just because a chain of radical extensions can be expanded to normal extensions doesn't justify we need to have normality condition for solvability. It is imperative that solvability needs normal extensions otherwise we cannot solve the polynomial in the extension field in the first place. Also, only normal radical extensions can be abelian since we can swap the roots when they are expressed as factors.

Comment: Solvable and separable is the same as contained in a tower of abelian extensions which is the same as contained in a tower of cyclic extensions which in turn is the same as separable radical extension. The non-separable case reduces to adding a purely inseparable layer which is radical.